# Existing website + BugNET + YAF ASP.NET Membership Integration

Tags: c#, integration, membership, bug-tracking, yaf

Ok I have a group of three web applications.

My existing web application doesn't have any customization whatsoever, it just used the basic membership providers.

[YAF.NET](http://yetanotherforum.net) uses custom providers, the one that posed a problem was the custom profile provider:

```
<profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="YafProfileProvider" inherits="YAF.Utils.YafUserProfile">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="yafnet" applicationName="YetAnotherForum" name="YafProfileProvider" type="YAF.Providers.Profile.YafProfileProvider"/>
    </providers>
</profile>
```

So I integrated this with my main site, by just adding the reference to `YAF.Utils` and the `inherits="YAF.Utils.YafUserProfile"` attribute to my profile provider on the main site.

But now I'm trying to also integrate [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com) into the mix. [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com) has the following customization of their membership implementation:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ExtendedSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ExtendedSqlMembershipProvider" type="BugNET.Providers.MembershipProviders.ExtendedSqlMembershipProvider, BugNET.Providers.MembershipProviders.ExtendedSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="BugNET" description="Extended Membership API" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="BugNET" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<profile enabled="true" automaticSaveEnabled="false" defaultProvider="MyProfileProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyProfileProvider" type="Altairis.Web.Providers.SimpleSqlProfileProvider, Altairis.Web.Providers" connectionStringName="BugNET" tableName="BugNet_UserProfiles" keyColumnName="UserName" lastUpdateColumnName="LastUpdate" />
    </providers>
    <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="String" customProviderData="FirstName;nvarchar;100" />
        <add name="LastName" type="String" customProviderData="LastName;nvarchar;100" />
        <add name="DisplayName" type="String" customProviderData="DisplayName;nvarchar;150" />
        <add name="IssuesPageSize" type="Int32" defaultValue="10" customProviderData="IssuesPageSize;int" />
        <add name="NotificationTypes" type="String" defaultValue="Email" customProviderData="NotificationTypes;nvarchar;255" />
        <add name="PreferredLocale" type="String" defaultValue="en-US" customProviderData="PreferredLocale;nvarchar;50" />
  <add name="SelectedIssueColumns" type="String" defaultValue="" customProviderData="SelectedIssueColumns;nvarchar;50" />
    </properties>
</profile>
```

In what way should I merge all three web.configs?

My goal is to have the following application structure:

- www.website.com       *[Main site]*
- forum.website.com     *[YAF.NET](http://yetanotherforum.net)*
- tracker.website.com  *[BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com)*

And all three integrated under the same [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) Membership model.

In order to accomplish this I obviously need to

1. Use the same machine key in all web config files, or so I've read?
2. I think there was something about telling all three applications what the "web root" was? As in, setting it to *"www.website.com"*
3. Merge the membership profiles, how would I achieve this, I've read somewhere that [YAF](http://yetanotherforum.net)'s implementation of inheriting from their custom profile provider overrides whatever is put into the `properties` node of the `profile` section. I have no problem editting their implementation, or source code. Should I perhaps edit into YAF.Utils.YafUserProfile the custom properties that are in [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com)'s implementation, and maybe also rename it as something more adequate, and perhaps put it in my main website solution?
4. What about the "extended membership provider" [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com) seems to be using? should I just test this out as-is and find out if they are compatible? Using different implementations in different solutions, is that compatible?
5. Is there anything else I might be missing?

On an additional note I should mention that I'm intending on having a special folder called `App_Shared`, which will in the main website project, and an svn-external to both [YAF.NET](http://yetanotherforum.net) and [BugNET](http://bugnetproject.com). There, I intend to place a Base master page all three applications should inherit from, so I can share some very basic details like a header, a footer, and a SiteMap.

All help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, But Dave Burk has done it perfectly in [Sueetie](http://www.Sueetie.com). It doesn't contain Bug.Net but It contains YAF, BlogEngine.Net, Screwturn Wiki and Gallery Server Pro. The source is free. download it and use it as a template.